# pandas DataFrame.from_dict doesn't result the right multiIndex where the keys of dict are tuple

Tags: python, pandas

When I want to transform a dict with tuple keys into a dataframe with multi-index, I used pandas.DataFrame.from_dict method. But I fund the result seems to be wrong.
Here is my code:

```
dict_var1 = Counter({('w1', 's1'): 47, ('w2', 's1'): 40, ('w3', 's2'): 35, ('w1', 's3'): 30, ('w4', 's4'): 28})
frame_var1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_var1, orient='index', columns=['num'])
print(frame_var1)
```

And the result is:

> ```
>                  num
>       (w1, s1)   47
>       (w2, s1)   40
>       (w3, s2)   35
>       (w1, s3)   30
>       (w4, s4)   28
> ```

The index of the frame is not multi-level. I feel confused about the result very much. Can anyone comment: 
1. Why does this function get this result? 
2. How can I achieve my goals?

Hope for reply. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create Series with `MultiIndex` and for one column DataFrame use [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
frame_var1 = pd.Series(dict_var1).to_frame('num')
print(frame_var1)

       num
w1 s1   47
w2 s1   40
w3 s2   35
w1 s3   30
w4 s4   28
```

Another solution is create `MultiIndex` by tuples with [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(dict_var1.keys())
frame_var1 = pd.DataFrame(list(dict_var1.values()), index=mux, columns=['num'])

print(frame_var1)

       num
w1 s1   47
w2 s1   40
w3 s2   35
w1 s3   30
w4 s4   28
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your solutions. I find that pd.DataFrame.from_dict can result in muli-index in some cases. Here is an example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244973/dictionary-to-multi-index-pandas-dataframe). So I wonder why it doesn't work with dict_var1.

Comment: Thanks again and I've already accepted your answer. I try to modify dict_var1 as: dict_var1 = {('a', 'b'): [43,47], ('a', 'c'): [23,40], ('b', 'c'): [30,35], ('c', 'd'): [10,30], ('a', 'd'): [23,28]}. But pd.DataFrame.from_dict still doesn't result in multi-index. I feel confused about this.